# Automatic mobile redirect according to the page they are trying to access

Tags: javascript, mobile

So after messing with responsiveness this week to allow mobile users to view my site with ease i have found its not for me, So i've decided to go ahead and use the /mobile/ at the end of my domain (www.example/com/mobile/).

I've managed to get all users that goto my site to goto the mobile site fine using everything up to a tablet. All is well!

However lets say I have a specific page for example www.example.com/display/page/650/

When that is shared on FB/TW the link that is shared is for the desktop version.

How do I get the mobile user to goto www.example.com/mobile/display/page/650/

What I'm currently using for mobile direction.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 750) {
document.location = "mobile";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Clearly it says redirect to www.example.com/mobile, Looked around but cant think of what the terms are for this to get them to goto the same page but the mobile version of it?

Thanks for the help peoples!

After a year of work my project is nearly done! Just the mobile side left now!

Comment: Have been looking around all day today, Cant find anything? Any geniuses out there that can shed some light on this? Thanks